# How do I get the node/entity from an instance of entity_metadata_wrapper in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-entities

How do I get a reference to the node/entity used to instantiate entity_metadata_wrapper / EntityDrupalWrapper. I could not find a `getNode`/`getEntity` or similar method in the 
[EntityDrupalWrapper API Reference](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/class/EntityDrupalWrapper/7).

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', 
        entity_create('node', array(
            'type' => 'video',
            'bundle' => 'video'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: `$wrapper->value()` or `$wrapper->raw()` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityMetadataWrapper provides two methods for getting node data, `raw` and `value`. Description of `raw` from [EntityMetadataWrapper API Reference](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/class/EntityMetadataWrapper/7).

> Returns the raw, unprocessed data. Most times this is the same as
>   returned by value(), however for already processed and sanitized
>   textual data, this will return the unprocessed data in contrast to
>   value().

Credit to @Clive for answer